# How to make Android phone's firefox open my wordpress on pc?

Tags: android, apache, firefox, debian

Environment:debian9 + apache2.

```
ifconfig
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.31.52  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.31.255
```

The setting for apache2.

```
sudo cat  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.con
<VirtualHost 192.168.31.52:80>
DocumentRoot  /home/content/mydoc
</VirtualHost>  

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot /home/content/mydoc
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|json)$">
    FileETag None

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header unset ETag
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
      Header set Pragma "no-cache"
      Header set Note "CACHING IS DISABLED ON LOCALHOST"
      Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>


Alias   /wp  "/var/www/html/wp"
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When to input `127.0.0.1` in my local pc's firefox ,all webpage in `/home/content/mydoc` displayed.
When to input `127.0.0.1/wp` in my local pc's firefox ,all webpage in `/var/www/html/wp` displayed.
When to input `192.168.31.52` in my local pc's firefox ,all webpage in `/home/content/mydoc` displayed.
When to input `192.168.31.52/wp` in my local pc's firefox ,all webpage in `/var/www/html/wp` displayed.
Now i want to open webpage page in `/home/content/mydoc` with my android phone,input `http://192.168.31.52` ,why can't connect to the apache2 server in pc via my android phone's firefox?

```
sudo iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 7204 7355K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   44  2578 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
   16  1638 INPUT_direct  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
   16  1638 INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
   16  1638 INPUT_ZONES  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
   16  1638 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 FORWARD_direct  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 6411 packets, 1521K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 6419 1521K OUTPUT_direct  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  +      any     anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  any    +       anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_public_log  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 FWDI_public_deny  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 FWDI_public_allow  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_public_log  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 FWDO_public_deny  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 FWDO_public_allow  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   16  1638 IN_public  all  --  +      any     anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_public (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   16  1638 IN_public_log  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
   16  1638 IN_public_deny  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
   16  1638 IN_public_allow  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: Are you connected via WIFI or Cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo cat  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
<VirtualHost 192.168.31.52:80>
DocumentRoot  /home/content/mydoc
<Directory /home/content/mydoc>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>  

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot /home/content/mydoc
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|json)$">
    FileETag None

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header unset ETag
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
      Header set Pragma "no-cache"
      Header set Note "CACHING IS DISABLED ON LOCALHOST"
      Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>


Alias   /wp  "/var/www/html/wp"
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming httpd is started and listening on every interfaces, and that the Android device is on the same network, a possible cause is the firewall blocking the connection, use :

```
iptables -L -v
```

to list the filter rules.

You can (temporarily) add a rule to allow connection to the http port :

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

If it does solve the problem, you will have to find how your firewall is configured to make the change more permanent.